# Dice problem involving nine randomly selected cups

Tags: probability, dice

I was given this problem by a colleague, and I cannot figure it out.

Given nine cups and an unlimited supply of six-sided dice rolled one at a time, what is the probability that you will, at some point, obtain a value of exactly seven in each of the nine cups, if the cup into which any given dice lands is completely random?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Why don't you take the [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) and earn your first badge? Just a heads-up, if this puzzle is purely mathematical, it may be closed, unless there is a more lateral solution.

Comment: This would make a nice Euler Project question. Maybe is already is. If it is, I'll remove the detailed answer, and just show the idea. Let me know if anyone knows.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be an exhausting bash with no nice solving method

Comment: Can this be transferred to the math se? It's an interesting probability problem, and I'd be interested to see what they do?

Comment: Math.SE  would want you to provide [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and a little more clarity to what the question is looking for. If you add that here I'll migrate it. (@DrXorile)

Answer (score 5):

So the probability is vanishingly small. It is (I believe) $1.274\times10^{-10}$. Or, to be exact:

```
1580941466784207610825588390565400459910497074701370825267293858713643202540644069402625/  
12408574807343622185064460000854792067100180333248751160777882097868222836057400196426369022820352
```

I used recursive programming with python to get this. I'll throw the code below for people to audit. But remember, to understand recursive programming, you must first understand recursive programming.

The *idea* of the code is to create a state of the total throw in the 9 cups. I keep the state sorted to reduce the number of possible states to a manageable number (11,440).

I then have a function (prob) that figures out the probability of eventually getting (7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7) from a given starting point. It works in terms of itself (which is the recursive part).

So, for a simplified example:
\begin{eqnarray}
prob((1,0,0)) &=& \frac{1}{18}(prob((2,0,0))+prob((3,0,0))+\cdots+prob((7,0,0)))\\
&+& \frac{2}{18}(prob((1,1,0))+prob((2,1,0))+\cdots+prob((6,1,0))
\end{eqnarray}
where the denominator of the fractions is the number of states (3 in the simple example, 9 in the actual example) multiplied by the number of throws (6); and the numberators is the number of cups effected.

By using the fractions module we keep everything exact. And the memoize code just means that when I call prob more than once, it saves the answer from the previous occasion.

Code is below:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import fractions

class memoize:
  def __init__(self, function):
    self.function = function
    self.memoized = {}

  def __call__(self, *args):
    try:
      return self.memoized[args]
    except KeyError:
      self.memoized[args] = self.function(*args)
      return self.memoized[args]

def add_dice(d,tot,add):
    """d is a dictionary, tot is the total in the cup(s)
    d[tot] is the number of cups with tot in them, and add
    is the new throw added to one of them.
    Returns state= (n1,n2,...,n9). n1>=n2>=...>=n9"""
    d[tot]+=-1
    d[tot+add]+=1
    s = []
    for k in d:
        s+=[k]*d[k]
    s.sort(reverse=True)
    return tuple(s)

@memoize
def prob(state):
    """state = (n1,n2,...,n9). n1>=n2>=...>=n9
    is the score in the cups.
    Returns p(success)"""
    if state[0]==7 and state[-1]==7:
        return fractions.Fraction(1,1)
    #Convert to dictionary 
    a = defaultdict(int)
    for s in state:
        a[s]+=1
    probability=fractions.Fraction(0)
    for k in a:
        for d in range(1,min([7,8-k])):
            suc = prob(add_dice(a.copy(),k,d))
            probability += suc*fractions.Fraction(a[k],len(state)*6)
    return probability

print(prob((0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)))
```

---

It is easy enough to confirm this in simpler instances. For example: prob((0,)) gives you 70993/279936, which can be confirmed by multiplying out a Markov chain matrix, or just looking at the tree.

Here's the other ways of working out the 1 cup scenario, which is already a challenging puzzle. In this scenario, we are assuming just 1 cup and asking how often it ends up on 7.

We can, in this scenario, consider 7 throws. There are $6^7=279936$ possible throws. We then have to look at how many of them add to 7 when we are allowed to throw away as many as we need to. So (6,1,x,x,...) and (1,6,x,x,...) would work, and would each have $6^5=7776$ items. You would need to continue in this way. There might be a clever way of counting them all, but I can't see it right now. The generalization to 9 cups would be horrible.

You might wonder why we can't just look at $7\times9=63$ throws in the 9 cups case (I say “just” but obviously this is already a lot). The problem is that you wouldn't necessarily be limited to just 7 throws in a single cup, so the number of possibilities grows dramatically from there. Hence the huge denominator above.

The alternative is to look at a Markov chain. One *might* be able to generalize a Markov chain more easily, but it would involve a matrix that was $11,441\times11441$ being multiplied to itself a number of times. The matrix is relatively sparse, but this is probably still a bit of work.

Anyway, it's a nice example in the one cup case, and it confirms that the above code works at least in this simple(r) case.

So to do a Markov Chain, we need to envision 9 states:

1. Score of 0
2. Score of 1
3. Score of 2
4. Score of 3
5. Score of 4
6. Score of 5
7. Score of 6
8. Score of 7
9. Bust.

We then need a matrix to hold the probabilities of transitioning from one state to the next with an additional throw:

\begin{equation}M=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{2}{6} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{3}{6} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{4}{6} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{5}{6} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}\end{equation}

Where the value in row $i$ and column $j$ shows the probability of moving from the $i$th state to the $j$th state. Note that if we get to a score of 7 or if we get to bust we stay there.

Our starting position is 0, which we represent as
\begin{equation}S=\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
\vdots \\
0
\end{bmatrix}\end{equation}

We know that we will be done within 7 throws, one way or another, so we need to work out $S.M^7$. Actually $S.M^8$ will also be fine, and is easier computationally because we can just keep squaring our result. But computers can handle these little calculations easily.

\begin{equation}
S.M^n=\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \frac{70993}{279936} \\ \frac{208943}{279936} \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
for any $n\geq7$. So the probability of ending on 7 with one cup is $\frac{70993}{279936}$ in agreement with our running prob((0,)). The code to do this is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import fractions

S = np.matrix([1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
f = fractions.Fraction(1,6)
M = np.matrix([[0,f,f,f,f,f,f,0,0],
          [0,0,f,f,f,f,f,f,0],
          [0,0,0,f,f,f,f,f,f],
          [0,0,0,0,f,f,f,f,2*f],
          [0,0,0,0,0,f,f,f,3*f],
          [0,0,0,0,0,0,f,f,4*f],
          [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,f,5*f],
          [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
          [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]])

print(S*M**7)
```